# The file is being used by another process error when building solution in VIsual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

When building a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2010 I have a following problem occurs:

69: "Unable to copy file "bin\Debug\MyApplication.exe". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

I can release and remove this file manually using "Unlocker" application and there I can see that a devenv.exe blocks my application (The Visual Studio itself). What are the possible reasons for this and how it can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, there is a squirrel loose in VS 2010 on this one.  There are multiple causes.  The workaround in [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571961/bug-on-build-solution-unable-to-copy-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process) fixed the problem for me the first time.

But it happened again.  Just search in Google using your own post title, you will find like 5 different causes.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked the *Enable the Visual Studio hosting process*

in Project properties -> Debug tab